# How to filter out bots from server requests

Tags: request, user-agent, bots

I'm tracking all requests to my server, and was hoping to filter out bots/crawlers from my statistics as they messes up what I'm looking for: See real traffic by human beings to my webpage.

I started creating a HTTP_USER_AGENT blacklist using various lists out there, but new bots/crawlers keep popping up - often in short massive bursts. I can't find any good way of identifying them.

The opposite solution would be to create a whitelist of valid HTTP_USER_AGENT strings, which will also have som major drawbacks.

Any ideas on this matter?

Comment: robots.txt file at the root of your server. http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: HTTP_USER_AGENT is the easier thing in the world to change. don't rely on it.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Will add robot.txt - it will help, but not 100% though - wonder how google analytics does this.

Comment: @terjeto: It detects the number of simultaneous requests, and the interval between all requests.